# how to use simpleaudioengine to play audio in a specified duration

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, duration, simpleaudioengine

i want to use SimpleAudioEngine to play a 2s mp3, but not so simple. I want to this audio plays 4s, that it, this mp3's duration should be 4s. Any good idea can solve this problem, Thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file to be 4 seconds using audacity audio editor.  You can extend the file without changing the pitch of the audio.  Then export the file as a separate mp3 file.  Then just pay the file normally.